# After removing a key from ec2 instance I can still access with that key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ssh-keys

I replaced the old public key in `authorized_keys` file on an ec2 instance with a new public key. I restarted the ssh service with `sudo service sshd restart` but I can still access the ec2 instance with the old key.

Comment: For additional context: the new key works fine as well. I can access with both of them.

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check if you removed the authorized keys for all users
- Check userdata if the scripts add ssh keys
- Check /etc/sshd/sshd_config (path might differ on other systems) if additional authorized_keys files are configured
- Reboot the system

Comment: I resolved by rebooting my local system. For some reason the new key was stored in my user session